# Mi app react no envia datos desde el navegador de un movil y si desde el navegador de la PC

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

Tengo un app construida con react y manejo las rutas con react-router-dom, todo el enrutado funciona bien desde el **navegador de mi pc** , el problema es cuando trato de entrar desde el **navegador del movil**, veo toda la interface pero cuando lleno el formulario de signUp no me envia los datos desde el **navegador del movil** y si los envia desde el **navegador del PC** , agradeceria una ayuda , Toda la problematica puede estar contenida quizas mas en que uso la manera de concebir los formulñarios a traves de **ant design** mediante sus hoot useRoutes en el signIn component  y en

**fichero App**

```
    import "antd/dist/antd.min.css";
    import { RouteWithSubRoutes } from "./config/routes";
    import "./App.scss";

     function App() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div>
              <RouteWithSubRoutes />
            </div>
          </Router>
      );
     }

      export default App;
```

**fichero RouteWithSubRoutes**

```
     import LayoutAdmin from "../layouts/LayoutAdmin";
     import LayoutBasic from "../layouts/LayoutBasic";
     
     import AdminHome from "../pages/Admin/";
     import AdminSignIn from "../pages/Admin/SignIn/SignIn";      
     import SignIn from "../pages/Admin/SignIn/SignIn";

     import Error404 from "../pages/Error404";

     function RouteWithSubRoutes() {
       let element = useRoutes([
         {
            element: <LayoutAdmin />,
           children: [
              { path: "/admin/", element: <AdminHome /> },
              { path: "admin/login", element: <AdminSignIn /> },
            ],
         },
         {
            path: "*",
            element: <Error404 />,
           },
         ]);
        return element;
       }
        export { RouteWithSubRoutes };
```

**fichero SignIn**

```
import { Layout, Tabs } from "antd";
//import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Logo from "../../../assets/img/png/3.1 logo-white.png";
import RegisterForm from "../../../components/Admin/RegisterForm";
import LoginForm from "../../../components/Admin/LoginForm/LoginForm";

export default function SignIn() {
  const { Content } = Layout;
  const { TabPane } = Tabs;

  return (
    <Layout className='sign-in'>
      <Content className='sign-in__content'>
        <h1 className='sign-in__content-logo'>
          <img src={Logo} alt='Logo' />
        </h1>
        <div className='sign-in__content-tabs'>
          <Tabs type='card'>
            <TabPane tab={<span>Login</span>} key='1'>
              <LoginForm />
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tab={<span>SignUp</span>} key='2'>
              <RegisterForm />
            </TabPane>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

**fichero LayoutAdmin**

```
      import { Layout } from "antd";
      import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
      import MenuTop from "../components/Admin/MenuTop/MenuTop";
      import MenuSider from "../components/Admin/MenuSider";
      import { RouteSignIn } from "../config/routes";
      import { getAccessToken } from "../api/auth";
      import "./LayoutAdmin.scss";

      export default function LayoutAdmin() {
         const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;
         const [menuCollapsed, setMenuCollapsed] = useState(true);
         const user = false;

         const token = getAccessToken();
         console.log(token);
         if (!user) {
            return <RouteSignIn />;
         }

        return (
            <Layout>
               <MenuSider menuCollapsed={menuCollapsed} />
               <Layout className='layout-admin' style={{ marginLeft: 
                menuCollapsed ? "80px" : "200px" }}>
                  <Header className='layout-admin__header'>
                    <MenuTop menuCollapsed={menuCollapsed} 
                      setMenuCollapsed={setMenuCollapsed} />
                   </Header>
                   <Content className='layout-admin__content'>
                     <Outlet />
                   </Content>
                   <Footer className='layout-admin__footer'> Footer 
                   </Footer>
                </Layout>
            </Layout>
           );
          }
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo le hacemos nosotros para ayudarte? No somos adivinos para saber qué hiciste mal en tu código para que no te funcione. Expón tu pregunta con datos concretos. Si te falla la lógica que maneja el envío de formulario, adjúntala a tu pregunta. Tal y como está es difícil que alguien pueda ayudarte, y probablemente termine cerrada.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando localmente? Si fuese así, la razón por la que te da el error es por estar usando un puerto específico de la PC para el despliegue local; obviamente el móvil no tendrá el mismo puerto para hacer las peticiones.

Comment: disculpen uds mi torpeza , enseguida ofrecere mas datos

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822